# Different python versions in centos

Tags: linux, python-2.7, centos7

I have a centos 7 machine , which has 2 python versions , python giver sveriosn 2.7.5 and python2.7 givers version . 2.7.13. I want to make 2.7.13 as default version, such that when I check python --version it gives 2.7.13 and not 2.7.5 . I have added both to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

If you set Python 2.7.13 to your PATH and not 2.7.5, the used Python should be 2.7.13.
Or you can try to set the `PYTHONPATH` variable